# Get user city location ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently building a ruby on rails app and I want to know if it is possible to get city name where the user is located when he uses the app.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add geocoder gem and run bundle install in terminal to get it installed

  gem 'geocoder'
- In any controller, You can get remote ip, city, country, lat and long..etc by using the below code

  request.location.ip            # to get user remote ip

  request.location.city          # to get user city

Comment: How to see the effect of request.location.ip and request.location.city im my development environment. It gives empty string